# Who created most of the tag excerpts and can they be changed?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, for [the mythology tag](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) the description reads:

> For questions about stories that are part of Hindu religious beliefs.
>   Hindu mythology can be found throughout Hindu scriptures like the
>   Vedas, Puranas, Ramayana, and Mahabharata

My questions:

**1) Who created most of the tag excerpts on HSE and can they be changed? Were they created by SE community Mods or HSE Mods?**

**2) Are they strict rules or just guidelines?**

Keeping in mind the site's gradual progress and evolution can they be altered and improved upon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Who can create or edit tag excerpts?

Any user can propose/suggest tag excerpt and tag wiki. Users having [tag approve privilege](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) can approve or reject tag wiki suggestions. Trusted users i.e users having [tag wiki edit privilege](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) can directly edit tag excerpt and wiki with an immediate effect.

#### Who created most of the tag excerpts?

Credits go to users who have been contributing to the community from early stages. You can check the history of tag excerpts and wikis by `history` or `excerpt history` link from tag info page to find out contributors.

---

Guidelines for using tags and creating tag excerpts are available in the help centre:

- [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)
- [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts)

---

> Q. Keeping in mind the site's gradual progress and evolution can they be altered and improved upon?

Yes, it's encouraged.

Comment: OK. But what about my Q- 2? I don't think they are rules. They are just guidelines and can be updated at any moment by anyone of us, right? Will select the answer after i see the update from you.

Comment: @Rickross Why are you distinguishing rules and guidelines? They should be followed like rules. And yes, they can be changed or updated.

Comment: Pandya- Because i used to think that rules are made by the Mods only and not by the users.. But as far as the Tag excerpts are concerned, they are created by the users and not by the Mods.